# Fontawesome en polymer 2

Tags: polymer, font-awesome

Al intentar cargar el script de fontawesome en un componente de polymer 2 no consigo que se vean los iconos. Esto es lo que hago:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

<dom-module id="mi-icono">
  <template>
    <i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
  </template>

  <script>
    /**
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     */
    class MiIcono extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'mi-icono'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          icono : String
        };
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MiIcono.is, MiIcono);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto sucede porque no pertenece tu script al componente, polymer está basado en web components, lo que era dentro de dom-module es el html que se inyecta al shadow robot y el código del script es la definición del custom element. Puedes intentar usar los iconos de font awesome importando en el html el cdn. Aunque te recomiendo usar los iconos de polymer https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/iron-icons